# Check if a Csv file contains column in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using [Maatwebsite/Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) to import a file and store the data in the DB.

I want to check if the column `registered` is in the file otherwise create a new value for it. I tried my code below but when I check my DB I see that the column `created_at` (`timestamp`) has the date of today's date and not what's on the column of the csv file.

Is it because of the migration that the row isn't updating ?

Because I have `$table->timestamps();` in the `User` migration.

```
class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithHeadingRow, WithUpserts
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
            'password' => $row['pass'],
            'created_at' => !empty($row['registered']) ? Carbon::parse($row['registered']) : Carbon::now(),
        ]);
    }

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ","
        ];
    }

    public function uniqueBy()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
}
```

Comment: did u get any error ?

Comment: @Pradeep the error is when i check my DB i see that the column `created_at` (timestamp) has the date of today's date and not whats on the column of the csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `created_at` column mass assignable in your `User` model? I think because of you are using [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) you have to set your `created_at` column as mass assignable. You can use `guarded` or `fillable` property to achieve this.

You can read more from Laravel Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `created_at` in the `$fillable` in my model